# How to plot the heat map for a given function in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a function called `func(mu, gamma)` . For each combination of `mu` and `gamma`, the function will return a value, let's call it `return_value`.

Now I have set range for `mu` and `gamma`:

```
mu = np.linspace(0,1,100)
gamma = np.linspace(0,1,100)
```

Now we have 1e4 combinations and each combinations corresponds to a `return_value`. I want to plot a heatmap for `return_value`.

I have tried to use `pcolor` in Python. However, from the example in the documentation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make these smaller to increase the resolution
dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05

# generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),
                slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)
# x and y are bounds, so z should be the value *inside* those bounds.
# Therefore, remove the last value from the z array.
z = z[:-1, :-1]
z_min, z_max = -np.abs(z).max(), np.abs(z).max()
```

because the defined function `fun` in my script can not take array as input, it does not work and I get this message if I follow the example:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Below is my code for `func`:

```
def fun(mu, gamma2):
    Isolation_Ratio = []
    kappa1 = gamma2
    kappa2 = gamma2                         
    gamma1 = gamma2
    g0 = gamma2 + kappa2 + gamma1 + kappa1
    gammag = kappa1/2. + gamma1/2.
    gamma = gamma2/2. + kappa2/2.
    for ii in range(len(rangedeltaw)):

        deltaw = rangedeltaw[ii]

        Forward_delta = forward_delta(mu, deltaw)
        Backward_delta = backward_delta(mu, deltaw)

        forward_root1, forward_root2, forward_root3 = forward_root(mu, deltaw)
        test_D, backward_root1, backward_root2, backward_root3 = backward_root(mu, deltaw)

        Root1.append(backward_root1)
        Root2.append(backward_root2)
        Root3.append(backward_root3)

        root1.append(forward_root1)
        root2.append(forward_root2)
        root3.append(forward_root3)
        if Forward_delta >= 0 and Backward_delta >= 0:
            a2sq = [max([forward_root1.real, forward_root2.real, forward_root3.real])]
            b1sq = [max([backward_root1.real, backward_root2.real, backward_root3.real])]
            A2sq.append(max([forward_root1.real, forward_root2.real, forward_root3.real]))
            B1sq.append(max([backward_root1.real, backward_root2.real, backward_root3.real]))
            for ii in range(len(a2sq)):
                for jj in range(len(b1sq)):

                    Isolation_Ratio.append(kappa2*a2sq[ii]/(kappa1*b1sq[jj]))
        elif Forward_delta >= 0 and Backward_delta < 0:
            a2sq = [max([forward_root1.real, forward_root2.real, forward_root3.real])]
            b1sq = [backward_root1.real]
            A2sq.append(max([forward_root1.real, forward_root2.real, forward_root3.real]))
            B1sq.append(backward_root1.real)
            for ii in range(len(a2sq)):
                for jj in range(len(b1sq)):
                    Isolation_Ratio.append(kappa2*a2sq[ii]/(kappa1*b1sq[jj]))

        elif Forward_delta < 0 and Backward_delta >= 0:
            a2sq = [forward_root1.real]
            b1sq = [max([backward_root1.real, backward_root2.real, backward_root3.real])]
            A2sq.append(forward_root1.real)
            B1sq.append(max([backward_root1.real, backward_root2.real, backward_root3.real]))
            for ii in range(len(a2sq)):
                for jj in range(len(b1sq)):
                    Isolation_Ratio.append(kappa2*a2sq[ii]/(kappa1*b1sq[jj]))

        else:   
            A2sq.append(forward_root1.real)
            B1sq.append(backward_root1.real)
            Isolation_Ratio.append(kappa2*forward_root1.real/(kappa1*backward_root1.real))   



    x = Isolation_RangeDeltaw
    y = Isolation_Ratio


    return max(y)
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to **plot** a heatmap, or how to **obtain** it, given a function? In the latter case, it is impossible to tell how to vectorize `fun()` without actually seeing its code.

Comment: I am a little confused with the difference between plot and obtain. What I want to achieve is for example, we get data in this form: [1,2,3], [2,3,4]....The first two are used as coordinates, and the third one is the value for that coordinate. I think I can only use color to indicate the value associated with that coordinate if I want to plot it in 2D.

Comment: Obtaining means getting a 2D array with the values of the heatmap, given a function. Plotting means transforming this array into a picture. Which of these tasks do you have trouble with?

Comment: I see, for me it is both. I also do not find a way to store a value with 2d index.

Comment: I don't really understand what is "a value with 2d index" and how is it different from a 2D array. Again, please add the source code for `fun()`, without it it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: yes, it is a 2d array. I have added my source code. Basically it takes two variables mu,gamma2 as input and you will get an output which is a single value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, first, how to obtain the heatmap. `fun()` is still not self-contained (`forward_delta()` etc are not defined), so I cannot execute it, and you didn't specify at which line the error occurs, but I can guess that the offender is

```
if Forward_delta >= 0 and Backward_delta >= 0:
```

meaning that `forward_delta()` etc functions work with arrays. By the look of it, it may be possible to fully vectorize the function, but it is a non-trivial task and is a question of its own (and if you ever ask it, make sure to make a **[self contained example](http://sscce.org/)**). A simpler, although a less efficient solution is to just fill the heatmap value by value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def fun(mu, gamma):
    # your function

mu = numpy.linspace(0,1,100)
gamma = numpy.linspace(0,1,100)

# filling the heatmap, value by value
fun_map = numpy.empty((mu.size, gamma.size))
for i in range(mu.size):
    for j in range(gamma.size):
        fun_map[i,j] = fun(mu[i], gamma[j])
```

Now that you have the array, the second part of your question is how to plot it. [`pcolor()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) is used to visualize discreet arrays; [`imshow()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) suits your purpose better:

```
fig = plt.figure()
s = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, xlabel='$\\gamma$', ylabel='$\\mu$')
im = s.imshow(
    fun_map,
    extent=(gamma[0], gamma[-1], mu[0], mu[-1]),
    origin='lower')
fig.colorbar(im)
fig.savefig('t.png')
```

Note that in the array the X dimension is last (corresponds to `gamma`), but `imshow` puts the X dimension first.

The result for a simple function

```
def fun(mu, gamma):
    return numpy.sin(mu) + numpy.cos(gamma)
```

will look like

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.